# Discriminant of a Quadratic Polynomial

Tags: quadratics, discriminant

I am a little confused about how the author came to this discriminant of this quadratic polynomial. I understand that the discriminant comes from solving for a variable, and the discriminant is whatever is under the square root. Below is information directly from the PDF:

(1) $f(y) = (y^2 − v^2)(y − u)$,

with rational u, v. Indeed, to get all the roots of f rational, it is enough to assume that
u, v are rational.

The quadratic polynomial:

(2) $f'(y) = 3y^2 − 2yu − v^2$

has rational roots, if and only if its discriminant $4(u^2 + 3v^2)$ is the square of a rational
number.

How is the discriminate $4(u^2 + 3v^2)$? When I solve for $y$ in equation (2), I get $(u^2 + 3v^2)$ under the square root. I am guessing that the author is assuming that $4(u^2 + 3v^2)$ is the discriminant?

Answer (score 2):

We have $f'(y)=3y^2-2uy-v^2$. it is a quadratic equation in $y$. so discriminant is $$\Delta=(-2u)^2-4(3)(-v^2)=4u^2+4(3v^2)=4(u^2+3v^2)$$

Comment: Clears up everything. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to find the roots of a quadratic polynomial. First thing you want to figure out is how many real roots it has. How to do that? The discriminant tells you this exact type of information.

First, I would like to figure out the roots of the polynomial $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$. How can we figure out the roots? We can easily do that by setting $f(x) = 0$. Thus:
$$\begin{align*}
  f(x) = 0\\
  a x^2 + b x + c = 0
\end{align*}$$

Solving for $x$ in there can be done in many ways, but I will go with the completing the square idea. First step is to divide the entire equation by $a$ and then move constant terms to the right hand side:
$$\begin{align*}
  a x^2 + b x + c & = 0\\
  x^2 + \frac{b}{a} x + \frac{c}{a} & = 0\\
  x^2 + \frac{b}{a} x & = -\frac{c}{a}
\end{align*}$$

Now let us think about $(u + v)^2$. If you expand it, you will get:
$$\begin{align*}
  (u + v)^2 & = u^2 + uv + uv + v^2\\
  (\color{green}u + \color{blue}v)^2 & = \color{green}u^2 + 2\color{green}u\color{blue}v + \color{blue}v^2
\end{align*}$$

I will now highlight a few terms in the equation for the roots and also do a small manipulation. Maybe you will few comfortable about noticing a few things.
$$\begin{align*}
  \color{green}x^2 + \color{blue}{\frac{b}{a}}\color{green}x & = -\frac{c}{a}\\
  \color{green}x^2 + \color{red}2\color{green}x\color{blue}{\frac{b}{\color{red}{2}a}} & = -\frac{c}{a}\\
  (\color{green}x)^2 + 2(\color{green}x)\left(\color{blue}{\frac{b}{2a}}\right) & = -\frac{c}{a}
\end{align*}$$

If you look at the equation we got above, you will notice it is almost a perfect square. However, it is missing a term and we can add it to both sides.
$$\begin{align*}
  (\color{green}x)^2 + 2(\color{green}x)\left(\color{blue}{\frac{b}{2a}}\right) \color{red}{+ \left(\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2} & = -\frac{c}{a} \color{red}{+ \left(\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2}\\
  (\color{green}x)^2 + 2(\color{green}x)\left(\color{blue}{\frac{b}{2a}}\right) + \left(\color{blue}{\frac{b}{2a}}\right)^2 & = -\frac{c}{a} + \left(\color{blue}{\frac{b}{2a}}\right)^2\\
  \left(\color{green}x + \color{blue}{\frac{b}{2a}}\right)^2 & = \left(\color{blue}{\frac{b}{2a}}\right)^2 - \frac{c}{a}
\end{align*}$$

We can simplify the above but first we must notice that the solutions to $x^2 = n^2$ can be both $x = -n$ and $x = n$. Thus:
$$\begin{align*}
  x^2 = n^2\\
  x = \pm \sqrt{n^2}
\end{align*}$$

Going back to our problem:
$$\begin{align*}
  \left(x + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 & = \left(\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 - \frac{c}{a}\\
  \left(x + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 & = \frac{b^2}{4a^2} - \frac{c}{a}\\
  \left(x + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 & = \frac{b^2}{4a^2} - \frac{\color{red}{4a}c}{\color{red}{4a}a}\\
  \left(x + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 & = \frac{b^2}{4a^2} - \frac{4ac}{4a^2}\\
  \left(x + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 & = \frac{b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2}\\
  x + \frac{b}{2a} & = \pm \sqrt{\frac{b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2}}\\
  x + \frac{b}{2a} & = \pm \frac{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}\\
  x & = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}
\end{align*}$$

We have successfully found what gives us the roots of a quadratic polynomial. However, there is something which tells us the nature of these roots: the discriminant ($\Delta$).

In the formula we derived, the conditions for the roots to be real or not, is bounded to the square root. Thus, we define the inside of the square root as **the discriminant of the polynomial**.
$$\boxed{\Delta = b^2 - 4ac}$$

In the formula you provided, we have:
$$\begin{align*}
  f(y) & = 3y^2 - 2uy - v^2\\
  f(y) & = \color{red}{3}y^2 \color{red}{-2u}y \color{red}{-v^2}\\
  a & = 3\\
  b & = -2u\\
  c & = -v^2
\end{align*}$$

Therefore, your discriminant $\Delta$ will be:
$$\begin{align*}
  \Delta & = (-2u)^2 - 4(3)(-v^2)\\
  \Delta & = 4u^2 + 4(3v^2)\\
  \Delta & = 4(u^2 + 3v^2)
\end{align*}$$

Which is what you originally asked.